# Unable to toggle on and off location service using Appium

Tags: appium

I need to enable and disable location service in Android before my test. I have tried the following solutions but nothing worked at all.

Scenario : 1 
ADB commands

adb shell settings put secure location_providers_allowed +network,gps
adb shell settings put secure location_providers_allowed -network,gps

These commands working at times but not all the times so my test fails lot of times for disabling.

Scenario : 2 
toggleLocationService() Method

```
public static void enableAndDisableLocation(AppiumDriver<WebElement> driver) {
        ((AndroidDriver<WebElement>) driver).openNotifications();
        ((AndroidDriver<WebElement>) driver).toggleLocationServices();
    }
```

Are there any other solution to enable and disable Location service in Android using Appium. Also I want to know the status of the Location before enabling and disabling.

I am using Java client 5.0.4
Testing in Android Nougat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Enable:

```
adb shell settings put secure location_providers_allowed +gps
adb shell settings put secure location_providers_allowed +network
```

To Disable:

```
adb shell settings put secure location_providers_allowed -gps
adb shell settings put secure location_providers_allowed -network
```